# How can I open a .dump file on MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, dump

I was wondering if you could help me with the next question.

I have a big MySql Dump which I want to open with MySql Workbench, the thing is I have investigated on how to open it and in theory it should be very straight forward in the sense that it should automatically open with the import option that MySql Workbench gives you.

The whole query to extract the database is inside the .dump so I dont know what am I doing wrong that each time I try to open the .dump it says error and nothing happens.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you append the error to the question?

Comment: How large is the file? Most text editors can only deal with files up to maximum size, MySQL Workbench is no exception. I loaded files up to 256MB in an SQL editor, which is close to what you can open at all.

Comment: Hi guys! Well the file has an extension .DUMP and it is about 1,5 GB. I use the "Data Import/Restore" option which can be find at the left of MySql Workbench panel; then I use the option "Import from a Self-Contained file". I use this option because I have opened the .dump file and all the query of the database is inside it, in other words and based on what I have read, MySql should automatically detect the query and import the database. The error that MySql Workbench shows is: ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected. Thanks!

Comment: `No database selected` implies that a DB was not first selected to specify where the import data should go. Sometimes, there a line in the script that might have `USE yourDB;`. Some other scripts might have the database name as part of the table creation (and other statements), like this: `CREATE TABLE \`yourDB\`.\`yourTable\``. Perhaps there is an option in MySQL workbench where you can specify the DB where the import should go. I no longer have MySQL workbench, but perhaps someone else here may know. Of course, there's always the help of Google, or other MySQL workbench-related forums.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer!. So you mean maybe I should modify the script inside the .Dump file?.